# read an ip address conversely using python

Tags: python, linux

I want to write a short script using python that read my ip address conversely , so when I write `127.0.0.1` I should find as a result `1.0.0.127`.
any help please

Comment: Did you even searched a bit and tried some things ? If so, show us what you did before asking for a ready-to-use answer...

Comment: of course I searched ,but this is the first time I use python so I find it a little bit complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ip = '127.0.0.1'

ip = ip.split('.')

ip.reverse()

print('.'.join(ip))
```

If you want to preserve the original ip. it's very easy since strings are immutable in python assign it to a new variable and just call `reversed` on it instead of calling the list's `reverse()` so you don't alter the list also (if you want that)

```
ip = '127.0.0.1'

new = ip.split('.')

new = reversed(new)

print('.'.join(new))

print(ip)
```

Comment: thanks for helping , this seems the solution I am looking for ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
def reverseIP(ip):
    ip = ip.split(".")
    ip.reverse()
    return '.'.join(ip)
```

Example :

```
print(reverseIP("127.0.0.1")) # Prints 1.0.0.127
```